# Automating the removal of business units of disabled users

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have seen in some past questions on this topic that you had to manually remove business units from a disabled user.

Considering this itself is time intensive, paired with the fact that my filter of # of users and my filter of only disabled users is reset **every time I remove the business units from someone** I might be here awhile.

Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Every time you remove the user from the Business Unit, it always adds that user back and what you want to achieve is removing that user out of the Business Unit right?

Comment: Yes, I want disabled users removed from the business unit. I can do this manually by going to the list of users, finding ones labeled disabled, clicking them & unticking them from the business unit but it is incredibly time intensive considering the number of users there are. 
Time spent is added since there's multiple pages & it does not seem to save what page you were on, what filters you had, etc.